# Guava how to copy all files from one directory to another

Tags: java, io, guava

I have been experimenting with guava lately and I have not come across a way to copy all of the files from one directory to another. If anyone can point me in the right direction on how to do this that would be great.

Comment: What did you try so far?  What was the problem?  –  In general, you don’t need Guava to do that.  Have a look at [`java.io.File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) and [`java.nio.Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html).  This should be all you need.

Comment: @RobinKrahl I'm using java6 for this that's why I'm using guava.
Using the * operator doesn't seem to work and there seems like theres no "getFiles();" function either.

Comment: What about [`File.listFiles()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29)?

Comment: @RobinKrahl Like I said I'm using java6, Those are java7 functions.

Comment: `File.listFiles()` is also available in Java 6, according to the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

Guava is not providing any fancy file manipulation utilities apart from the rather rudimentary functionality in [Files](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html).

To copy files from one directories, please use a different library, e.g. [commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html).

Comment: There's [Files#copy](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#copy(java.io.File,%20java.io.File))