# Is there any way to copy a directory to another path using guava library?

Tags: java, directory, copy, guava

I know there is a method -`Files.copy()`- using guava library to copy a file, but what's the way to copy a directory in other path?
P.S: this question maybe similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689810/guava-how-to-copy-all-files-from-one-directory-to-another) but I'm wondering if there is any other way except copying files one by one.

Comment: Just FYI, recursive file operations in Java (unless implemented very carefully using `SecureDirectoryStream` in JDK7, and even then you can only implement recursive delete) are inherently vulnerable to a race where a directory is deleted and replaced with a symbolic link to a directory elsewhere. Particularly bad with delete, but could also be used to fill up your disk on a copy. That's part of why Guava doesn't have this and you should shell out to `cp` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guava is not providing any fancy file manipulation utilities apart from the rather rudimentary functionality in [Files](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html).

To copy whole directories, please use a different library, e.g. [commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectoryToDirectory](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html).